# Get Latitude,Longtitude by a stable marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, gis

I have to make an application with a marker on the center of a srceen and by moving the map 
and not the marker get lat,lon of the point that the marker shows. I have search the internet for something like Drag Marker but I am
not sure if this is what I need.Any Solution?

Comment: YOu could listen to map movments and recalculate the markers position

Comment: In android its quite difficult to listen map change. Android have touchListeners only. Try searching for draw circle on map centre. I did something similar. But my point follow the mapcentre with some delay. If your intrested in my code please let me know in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapActivity wrtie this.

```
Location l = new Location();
// Location class will be used to calculate distance moved by map
TimerTask tm;
GeoPoint oldCenterOfMap, newCenteOfMap;
```

// On your on resume method of activity do oldCenterOfMap = mapView.getMapCenter();

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
int isTouched = 0;
MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.yourmapview_from_xml);

mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
newCenteOfMap = mapView.getMapCenter();

if (mapchanged(oldCenterOfMap, newCenteOfMap)) {
isTouched++;

    // Here is what would you do when you lift your finger fromt he map*****
newCenteOfMap =mapView.getMapCenter());

if (isTouched >= 1) {
if (isTouched > 1) {
mHandler.removeCallbacks(tm_circle);
isTouched = 1;
}
mHandler.postDelayed(tm_circle, 1200);
}
}
if (!mapchanged(oldCenterOfMap, newCenteOfMap))
mHandler.removeCallbacks(tm_circle);
}

return false;
}
});


tm_circle = new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
isTouched = 0;
// here is what you do after you touched a map moved after 1.2 seconds
oldCenterOfMap = mapView.getMapCenter();

}
};


public boolean mapchanged(GeoPoint oldCenter, GeoPoint newCenter) {

    String distance = l.CalclauteDistance(oldCenter.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6,
            oldCenter.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
            newCenter.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6,
            newCenter.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);

    if (Double.valueOf(distance) == 0.0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Previous code would keep the track of the map movement.
Next code will respond in case of map movement.
In the comments present in the code above (    // here is what you do after you touched a map moved after 1.2 seconds AND // Here is what would you do when you lift your finger fromt he map*****) follow the instruction on my answer on another post.
Here [Adding multiple overlays on mapview dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826824/adding-multiple-overlays-on-mapview-dynamically/14827094#14827094)

Edit

```
public String CalclauteDistance(double long1, double lat1, double long2,
        double lat2) {
    String Result;
    Point p1 = new Point(long1, lat1);
    Point p2 = new Point(long2, lat2);
    Result = p1.distanceTo(p2) + "";
    return Result;

}
```

Here is the function (CalclauteDistance) from location class.

Comment: Thanks for sending me the code but I have a problem.At the point"l.CalclauteDistance"it tells me that is undefined for the type location.Should i change this method with an other?

Comment: you can use distanceTo or any other method avaliable in your API to calculate distance between two point. But please make sure the data type it returns. 10-hours from now, i'll update you with this methode also.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Here's the CalclauteDistance() method.