# Adding multiple overlays on mapview dynamically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I've a mapView on which I managed to get an overlay onLongPress with the help of GestureListener. What I actually want is, I want to add markers (with same icon) one by one. Like I want to mark different positions on map (not all at once). Any help with this would be great as am newbie with MapView and Overlays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ItemizedOverlay class to add drawable on specific longitudes and latitudes.

In your MapActivity write

GeoPoint your_point = (Provide geopoint information here);

Drawable drawable = 
this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_point_image);

HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
                        drawable, MapsActivity.this, mapView);
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (your_point.getLat() * 1E6),
                        (int) (your_point.getLon() * 1E6));

OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(your_point);

itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
                mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);

Where

HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay{

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Activity context,
            MapView mapView) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
        this.mapView = mapView;

```
}
```

}

I did it this way and it works.